# How measure characters I use with Azure Cognitive Services Speech Synthesis (TTS)?

Tags: azure, speech-recognition, text-to-speech, azure-cognitive-services

Is there a way to see qtty characters I use in the azure portal metrics? There is "SynthesizedCharacters" metric but I only view data when I use it from Speech Studio. I want to see this metric when I use cognitive sdk. Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, AFAIK there is no metric to track that from the Azure Portal. However, you can maintain the count locally at your end or the central location where you can query yourself --- add an additional logic to maintain the metrics in your code.

The character is counted based on the below conditions (that can be found [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/cognitive-services/Speech-Service/text-to-speech.md)):

- Text passed to the text-to-speech service in the SSML body of the
  request
- All markup within the text field of the request body in the SSML
  format, except for  and  tags
- Letters, punctuation, spaces, tabs, markup, and all white-space
  characters
- Every code point defined in Unicode